# XmlSerializer: serialize array of elements as strings with different element names

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

My array items can have different names, but they all have simple string values, e.g.:

```
<MyArray>
    <TypeA>foo</TypeA>
    <TypeA>bar</TypeA>
    <TypeB>bazz</TypeB>
</MyArray>
```

How do I achieve this?

I'm looking at the documentation on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

There is an example that looks like what I want, but I can't get it to work the way they say it should:

```
public class Employee {  
    public string Name;  
}

public class Group {  
    [XmlArrayItem("MemberName")]  
    public Employee[] Employees;  
}
```

The resulting XML will supposedly look like this:

```
<Group>  
    <Employees>  
        <MemberName>Haley</MemberName>  
    </Employees>  
</Group>
```

However, when I run this example, I get the following XML instead:

```
<Group>
    <Employees>
        <MemberName>
            <Name>Haley</Name> 
        </MemberName>
    </Employees>
</Group>
```

I'm assuming there's a mistake in the documentation (I don't see anything in their code that should magically result in the value of the class Employee being substituted by the value its Name property), but I'm actually interested in getting my XML to look like their (erroneous?) example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as soon as I posted the question: use XmlTextAttribute.

In their example, Employee class should have looked like this:

```
public class Employee {
    [XmlText]
    public string Name;
}
```

In my case, my collection can contain TypeA and TypeB, where each type has one member with an [XmlText] attribute.

Comment: Also, which shows my lack of familiarity with XML serialization, there's an option of having an array of items decorated with [XmlElement] instead of [XmlArray], which results in the individual items being serialized together with the top-level properties of the class. This is actually what I really needed, so I rewrote it as [XmlElement] List<TypeA> MyTypeACollection {get;set;} [XmlElement] TypeB MyTypeB {get;set;}